# Int Address in memory increasing by 4

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int x = 1,*t;
        float y = 1.50,*u;
        char k = 'c',*v;

        t = &x;
        u = &y;
        v = &k;

        printf("%p %p %p", t, u, v);

        t++;
        u++;
        v++;

        printf("  %p %p %p", t, u, v);

        return 0;
}
```

Hi i have made this code but here something unusual is happening , i am printing the addresses , when i increase the address of all then from my view increment in **int** would be **2** , **float** would be **4** and **char** would be **1** but i got the following :

```
0xbffa6ef8 0xbffa6ef0 0xbffa6eff  0xbffa6efc 0xbffa6ef4 0xbffa6f00
```

For **float** and **char** i think its correct but for **int** i don't know why it is giving so

Comment: Why do you think `int` should only be 2 bytes? You've just proven that it's 4 (which is entirely normal - `int` is 32 bits on most platforms). On the other hand, `short` may well be 2 bytes wide...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming the `sizeof(int)` is `2` on your system/envrionment.

However, Your assumption is not correct. The standard does not require the size of `int` to be `2` or anything specific.

As your program shows the size of `int` is `4` on your system/envrionment.

**Lesson to Learn:**
Never rely or assume on size of an type, **always** use `sizeof` to determine the size, that is the reason the standard provides `sizeof`.

Answer (score 1):

The memory address increment for `t` is given by `sizeof(int)`.

If `sizeof(int)` is different than what you expect t to be incremented by then your assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` data type is usually 4 bytes. a `short` or a `short int` data type is 2 bytes;

Answer (score 1):

> The actual size of integer types varies by implementation. The only guarantee is that the long long is not smaller than long, which is not smaller than int, which is not smaller than short.

or

> sizeof ( short int ) <= sizeof ( int ) <= sizeof ( long int )

---

> **But you can be sure that it will be atleast 16 bits in size.**

---

This will be helpful,[detailed informations regarding the size of basic C++ types.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/977676)